# Configuring LED pins as input on MACHxo2 board

Tags: input, mach, pins

I am attempting to configure the pins connected to the on board LEDs as input pins. Documentation states they are free i/o, but when I probe them with a scope it says they are outputting a "high" signal. This is on the MACHXO2 7000he cpld, but I assume the answer would be the same for any of the MACH boards.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You probably need to clarify what really is the question you are asking. It's not clear if you are asking why you are getting a "high" signal when measuring or if you have trouble configuring the pin.

Comment: Have you simulated the code to make sure it does behave OK in the ideal world? Say, in your test case in simulation you could set `1` and `0` on some output pin and having connected it to your target input trace whether it gets these zeros and ones.

Comment: I don't know what your electrical circuit is: is LED connected to VDD or VCC, because if to the ground, than that pin is basically configured as an output, did you try reconfiguring it to input? Anyway you better include your code and ucf file, at least nets for LEDs, everyone can get more understanding. My answer was downvoted so I'll be thinking about deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys sorry for taking so long to reply. I would attach a picture of the circuit but I currently have too low a reputation to do so.

The LEDs are connected to a VCC of 3.3V. What I found was that by de-soldering the LEDs from the board, I was free to use the pins they were connected to as free i/o because this would create an open circuit between the pins and the 3.3V.

The pins are supposed to already by free i/o but the LEDs were active low which caused my program to see them as high signals all the time, ultimately making these pins permanent outputs.

Anyway, there's my answer and I hope it makes sense and helps one of you out one of these days.

Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score -1):

You could try a `led blinking` example, like for example this:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
LIBRARY lattice;
USE lattice.components.all;

ENTITY blinking_led IS
   PORT(
      led  : BUFFER  STD_LOGIC);
END blinking_led;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF blinking_led IS
   SIGNAL  clk  : STD_LOGIC;
   --internal oscillator
   COMPONENT OSCH
      GENERIC(
            NOM_FREQ: string := "53.20");
      PORT( 
            STDBY    : IN  STD_LOGIC;
            OSC      : OUT STD_LOGIC;
            SEDSTDBY : OUT STD_LOGIC);
   END COMPONENT;
BEGIN
   --internal oscillator
   OSCInst0: OSCH
      GENERIC MAP (NOM_FREQ  => "53.20")
      PORT MAP (STDBY => '0', OSC => clk, SEDSTDBY => OPEN);
   PROCESS(clk)
      VARIABLE count :   INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 25_000_000;
   BEGIN
      IF(clk'EVENT AND clk = '1') THEN
         IF(count < 25_000_000) THEN
            count := count + 1;
         ELSE
            count := 0;
            led <= NOT led;
         END IF;
      END IF;
   END PROCESS;
END behavior;
```

For more reading please look at Lattice Diamond and MachXO2 Breakout Board [Tutorial](http://eewiki.net/display/LOGIC/Lattice+Diamond+and+MachXO2+Breakout+Board+Tutorial)

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @RenaudBompuis simply it is required functionality for the requested hardware, what did you find wrong in it?

Comment: The question is about configuring an existing output already connected to LEDS into an INPUT and he's having trouble understanding the results he gets from his measurement. I apologise if I don't see it, but in what way does your reply answer that question? To me you have pasted unrelated code to blink the LED, that's not answering the question.

Comment: @RenaudBompuis I can try to explain if further details are added. I thought it may be helpful, because configuring LEDs for blinking is similar to work with I/O.